# Link to the same DLL twice - Implicit and explicit at the same time

Tags: visual-c++, dll, static-linking, dynamic-linking, loadlibrary

The project on which I'm working, loads same library twice:

1. with LoadLibrary
2. statically loads the DLL with a lib file and " __declspec(dllimport/dllexport)".

What is happening in this case? Are these 2 "loadings" use same heap or share something else. E.g. is it same or similar as calling LoadLibrary twice?

My general problem is that I'm having stack corruption problems, when calling dll methods from exe via the second approach. And I'm wondering if the problem could be, because of the first loading? All projects use same RT, alignment and so on.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` doesn't always load a library.  It can instead increase the reference count of an already-loaded DLL.

Comment: Also, loading of static dependencies (`dllimport`) happen before you have a chance to call `LoadLibrary` (unless you use delay-loading) so your numbers are the opposite of the order things really happen.

Comment: Did you find the cause (most likely in your dynamic dll/lib import system") ?

Comment: Yes I found the root cause and it was not related to the DLL loading. The problem was in wrong structure alignment.

Comment: Also see [LoadLibrary Reference Counting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3809767). If its the same DLL, then its only loaded once. Additional `LoadLibrary` calls bump the reference count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *"statically loads the DLL with a lib file and _declspec(dllimport/dllexport)"* I assume you meant that that you compiled your executable with the *.lib* as a dependency, and at the runtime the *.dll* is automatically loaded by the exe (at the beginning). Here's a fragment from [FreeLibrary (surprisingly) MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The system maintains a per-process reference count for each loaded module. A module that was loaded at process initialization due to load-time dynamic linking has a reference count of one. The reference count for a module is incremented each time the module is loaded by a call to LoadLibrary. The reference count is also incremented by a call to LoadLibraryEx unless the module is being loaded for the first time and is being loaded as a data or image file.

So in other words, the *.dll* gets loaded at application startup (because you linked against it) and [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) just increments its ref count (). For more info you could also check [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx), or [this dll guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx).

There's absolutely no reason to use both approaches for the same *.dll* in the same application.

The 2nd approach is the preferred one, **if** the *.dll* comes with a *.h* file (that holds the function definitions exported by the library, needed at compile time) and a *.lib* file (that instructs the liker to add references from the *.dll* file into the executable).

The 1st approach on the other hand is the only way if you only have the *.dll* file and you somehow have the signatures of the functions it exports. In that case you must define in your app pointers to those functions and initialize them using `GetProcAddress`. There are cases when this approach is preferred, for example when the functionality in the *.dll* is needed only in a corner case of the program flow, in that case there's no point to link against the *.lib* file and load the *.dll* at app startup if let's say in 99% of the cases it won't be required. Also, a major advantage of this approach: if the *.dll* is somehow deleted then only the functionality related to it won't work (`LoadLibrary` will fail), while using the other approach, the application won't start.

Now, without details i can't get to the bottom of **this** specific problem you'r running into. You say that you call a function "normally" (from its definition in the *.h* file), it fails while if you call it (with the same arguments) using a function pointer it succeeds? What's the stack error message?

**Note**: From my experience a typical reason for stack corruptions in scenarios like this one is calling convention mismatch between the *caller* and the *callee* (**stdcall** vs **cdecl** or viceversa). Also mixing *Debug* and *Release* could introduce problems.